# What does fatal compile error C1083: Cannot open source file mean?

Tags: compiler-construction, precompiled-headers

> Error 1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   source file:
>   'FpDebug/BalanceGrabber.pch': No such
>   file or directory c1xx

Answer (score 2):

Is one of your cpp files configured to generate the precompiled header? I think this is missing. In the project settings/makefile or whatever you use you have to create the pch (precompiled header) first!

Answer (score 0):

Check your path: specifically, does `FpDebug/BalanceGrabber.pch` exist?

Or can you specify an absolute path for that .pch file? i.e., `C:\development\FpDebug/BalanceGrabber.pch`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is given because a source file is not found during compilation/linking. You nee to check the spelling of the names and the search paths. 
And of course, check if the file is at the requested location.