# Getting a Fatal Error C1083 when converting a project from vc 6.0 to vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am getting the following error when i converted  a project from vc6.0 to vs2008

The error code is

Error 1 fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'FpDebug/BalanceGrabber.pch': No such file or directory c1xx

where BalanceGrabber is my Project

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587254/what-is-this-error-code-for

Comment: Members I got the solution for this.
Problem was in creation of manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.pch is a Pre-Compiled Header: the output of StdAfx.cpp, essentially. A simple clean/rebuild should fix this, otherwise try clearing the output folders manually.